# Microsoft SQL Server para MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Preciso de uma ajuda.
Baixei um projeto em c# de controle de estoque, porém o banco de dados é pelo Microsoft SQL Server, e gostaria de usar o MySQL para conexão e registro de dados.

Segue exemplo de arquivos de conexão:

***Arquivo: DAL > DadosDaConexao.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DadosDaConexao
    {
        public static String servidor = @"@\SQLESTOQUEBOX";
        public static String banco = "estoque_box";
        public static String usuario = "estoqueBox";
        public static String senha = "estoqueBox";
        public static String StringDeConexao
        {
            get
            {
                return @"Data Source=" + servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + banco + ";User ID=" + usuario + ";Password=" + senha;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Arquivo: DAL > DALConexao.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DALConexao
    {
        private String _stringConexao;
        private SqlConnection _conexao;

        public DALConexao(String dadosConexao)
        {
            this._conexao = new SqlConnection();
            this.StringConexao = dadosConexao;
            this._conexao.ConnectionString = dadosConexao;
        }

        public String StringConexao
        {
            get { return this._stringConexao; }
            set { this._stringConexao = value; }
        }

        public SqlConnection ObjetoConexao
        {
            get { return this._conexao; }
            set { this._conexao = value; }

        }
        public void Conectar()
        {
            this._conexao.Open();
        }

        public void Desconectar()
        {
            this._conexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de formulário de configuração do banco de dados e conexão: ***Arquivo: configuracao_banco_de_dados.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DAL;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GUI
{
    public partial class configuracao_banco_de_dados : Form
    {
        public configuracao_banco_de_dados()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                StreamWriter arquivo = new StreamWriter("ConfiguracaoBanco.txt", false);
                arquivo.WriteLine(txtServidor.Text);
                arquivo.WriteLine(txtBanco.Text);
                arquivo.WriteLine(txtUsuario.Text);
                arquivo.WriteLine(txtSenha.Text);
                arquivo.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Arquivo Atualizado com sucesso!");
            }
            catch(Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        private void frmConfiguracaoBancoDados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader arquivo = new StreamReader("ConfiguracaoBanco.txt");
                txtServidor.Text = arquivo.ReadLine();
                txtBanco.Text = arquivo.ReadLine();
                txtUsuario.Text = arquivo.ReadLine();
                txtSenha.Text = arquivo.ReadLine();
                arquivo.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btTestar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                DadosDaConexao.servidor = txtServidor.Text;
                DadosDaConexao.banco = txtBanco.Text;
                DadosDaConexao.usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
                DadosDaConexao.senha = txtSenha.Text;
                //testar a conexao
                SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection();
                conexao.ConnectionString = DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao;
                conexao.Open();
                conexao.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Conexão efetuada com sucesso");
            }
            catch (SqlException errob)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro na conexão ao banco de dados \n" +
                                "Verifique os dados transcritos");
            }
            catch (Exception erros)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erros.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de formulário de cadastro de produtos: ***Arquivo: cadastro_produto.cs***

```
using BLL;
using DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Modelo;
using GUI;
using System.IO;

namespace GUI
{
    public partial class cadastro_produto : GUI.formulario_cadastro
    {
        public string foto = "";
        public cadastro_produto()
        {  
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operacao = "inserir";
            this.alteraBotoes(2);
        }
        private void LimpaTela()
        {
            txtCodigo.Clear();
            txtNome.Clear();
            txtDescricao.Clear();
            txtValorPago.Clear();
            txtValorVenda.Clear();
            txtQtde.Clear();
            this.foto = "";
            pbFoto.Image = null;
        }
        private void frmCadastroProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.alteraBotoes(1);
            //combo da categoria
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
            BLLCategoria bll = new BLLCategoria(cx);
            cbCategoria.DataSource = bll.Localizar("");
            cbCategoria.DisplayMember = "cat_nome";
            cbCategoria.ValueMember = "cat_cod";
            try
            {
                //combo da subcategoria
                BLLSubCategoria sbll = new BLLSubCategoria(cx);
                cbSubCategoria.DataSource = sbll.LocalizarPorCategoria((int)cbCategoria.SelectedValue);
                cbSubCategoria.DisplayMember = "scat_nome";
                cbSubCategoria.ValueMember = "scat_cod";
            }
            catch 
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Cadastre uma categoria");
            }
            //combo und medida
            BLLUnidadeDeMedida ubll = new BLLUnidadeDeMedida(cx);
            cbUnd.DataSource = ubll.Localizar("");
            cbUnd.DisplayMember = "umed_nome";
            cbUnd.ValueMember = "umed_cod";

        }

        private void txtValorPago_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (!txtValorPago.Text.Contains(","))
                {
                    e.KeyChar = ',';
                }
                else e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void txtValorPago_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtValorPago.Text.Contains(",") == false)
            {
                txtValorPago.Text += ",00";
            }
            else
            {
                if (txtValorPago.Text.IndexOf(",")==txtValorPago.Text.Length-1)
                {
                    txtValorPago.Text += "00";
                }
            }
            try
            {
                Double d = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorPago.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                txtValorPago.Text = "0,00";
            }
        }

        private void txtValorVenda_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (!txtValorVenda.Text.Contains(","))
                {
                    e.KeyChar = ',';
                }
                else e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void txtValorVenda_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtValorVenda.Text.Contains(",") == false)
            {
                txtValorVenda.Text += ",00";
            }
            else
            {
                if (txtValorVenda.Text.IndexOf(",") == txtValorVenda.Text.Length - 1)
                {
                    txtValorVenda.Text += "00";
                }
            }
            try
            {
                Double d = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorVenda.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                txtValorVenda.Text = "0,00";
            }
        }

        private void txtQtde_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8 && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '.')
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (!txtQtde.Text.Contains(","))
                {
                    e.KeyChar = ',';
                }
                else e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void txtQtde_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtQtde.Text.Contains(",") == false)
            {
                txtQtde.Text += ",00";
            }
            else
            {
                if (txtQtde.Text.IndexOf(",") == txtQtde.Text.Length - 1)
                {
                    txtQtde.Text += "00";
                }
            }
            try
            {
                Double d = Convert.ToDouble(txtQtde.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                txtQtde.Text = "0,00";
            }
        }

        private void btAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operacao = "alterar";
            this.alteraBotoes(2);
        }

        private void btSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //leitura dos dados
                ModeloProduto modelo = new ModeloProduto();
                modelo.ProNome = txtNome.Text;
                modelo.ProDescricao = txtDescricao.Text;
                modelo.ProValorPago = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorPago.Text);
                modelo.ProValorVenda = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorVenda.Text);
                modelo.ProQtde = Convert.ToDouble(txtQtde.Text);
                modelo.UmedCod = Convert.ToInt32(cbUnd.SelectedValue);
                modelo.CatCod = Convert.ToInt32(cbCategoria.SelectedValue);
                modelo.ScatCod = Convert.ToInt32(cbSubCategoria.SelectedValue);

                //obj para gravar os dados no banco
                DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
                BLLProduto bll = new BLLProduto(cx);
                if (this.operacao == "inserir")
                {
                    //cadastrar uma Produto
                    modelo.CarregaImagem(this.foto);
                    bll.Incluir(modelo);
                    MessageBox.Show("Cadastro efetuado: Código " + modelo.ProCod.ToString());

                }
                else
                {
                    modelo.ProCod = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);  
                    //alterar um produto
                    if ( this.foto == "Foto Original")
                    {
                        ModeloProduto mt = bll.CarregaModeloProduto(modelo.ProCod);
                        modelo.ProFoto = mt.ProFoto;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        modelo.CarregaImagem(this.foto);
                    }
                    bll.Alterar(modelo);
                    MessageBox.Show("Cadastro alterado");
                }
                this.LimpaTela();
                this.alteraBotoes(1);
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        private void cbCategoria_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //combo da categoria
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
            try
            {
                cbSubCategoria.Text = "";
                //combo da subcategoria
                BLLSubCategoria sbll = new BLLSubCategoria(cx);
                cbSubCategoria.DataSource = sbll.LocalizarPorCategoria((int)cbCategoria.SelectedValue);
                cbSubCategoria.DisplayMember = "scat_nome";
                cbSubCategoria.ValueMember = "scat_cod";
            }
            catch
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Cadastre uma categoria");
            }
        }

        private void btLoFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
            od.ShowDialog();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(od.FileName))
            {
                this.foto = od.FileName;
                pbFoto.Load(this.foto);
            }

        }

        private void btRmFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.foto = "";
            pbFoto.Image = null;
        }

        private void btLocalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             consulta_produto f = new consulta_produto();
            f.ShowDialog();
            if (f.codigo != 0)
            {
                DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
                BLLProduto bll = new BLLProduto(cx);
                ModeloProduto modelo = bll.CarregaModeloProduto(f.codigo);
                txtCodigo.Text = modelo.CatCod.ToString();
                //colocar os dados na tela
                txtCodigo.Text = modelo.ProCod.ToString();
                txtDescricao.Text = modelo.ProDescricao;
                txtNome.Text = modelo.ProNome;
                txtQtde.Text = modelo.ProQtde.ToString();
                txtValorPago.Text = modelo.ProValorPago.ToString();
                txtValorVenda.Text = modelo.ProValorVenda.ToString();
                cbCategoria.SelectedValue = modelo.CatCod;
                cbSubCategoria.SelectedValue = modelo.ScatCod;
                cbUnd.SelectedValue = modelo.UmedCod;
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(modelo.ProFoto);
                    pbFoto.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    this.foto = "Foto Original";
                }
                catch {}

                txtQtde_Leave(sender,e);
                txtValorPago_Leave(sender, e);
                txtValorVenda_Leave(sender, e); 
                alteraBotoes(3);
            }
            else
            {
                this.LimpaTela();
                this.alteraBotoes(1);
            }
            f.Dispose();

        }

        private void btExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Deseja excluir o registro?", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (d.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
                    BLLProduto bll = new BLLProduto(cx);
                    bll.Excluir(Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text));
                    this.LimpaTela();
                    this.alteraBotoes(1);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Impossível excluir o registro. \n O registro esta sendo utilizado em outro local.");
                this.alteraBotoes(3);
            }
        }

        private void btCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.alteraBotoes(1);
            this.LimpaTela();
        }

        private void pnBotoes_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btaddCategoria_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cadastro_categoria f = new cadastro_categoria();
            f.ShowDialog();
            f.Dispose();

            //combo da categoria
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
            BLLCategoria bll = new BLLCategoria(cx);
            cbCategoria.DataSource = bll.Localizar("");
            cbCategoria.DisplayMember = "cat_nome";
            cbCategoria.ValueMember = "cat_cod";
            try
            {
                //combo da subcategoria
                BLLSubCategoria sbll = new BLLSubCategoria(cx);
                cbSubCategoria.DataSource = sbll.LocalizarPorCategoria((int)cbCategoria.SelectedValue);
                cbSubCategoria.DisplayMember = "scat_nome";
                cbSubCategoria.ValueMember = "scat_cod";
            }
            catch
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Cadastre uma categoria");
            }

        }

        private void btaddSubCategoria_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cadastro_sub_categoria f = new cadastro_sub_categoria();
            f.ShowDialog();
            f.Dispose();

            //combo da categoria
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);

            try
            {
                //combo da subcategoria
                BLLSubCategoria sbll = new BLLSubCategoria(cx);
                cbSubCategoria.DataSource = sbll.LocalizarPorCategoria((int)cbCategoria.SelectedValue);
                cbSubCategoria.DisplayMember = "scat_nome";
                cbSubCategoria.ValueMember = "scat_cod";
            }
            catch
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Cadastre uma categoria");
            }
        }

        private void btAddUnidadeMedida_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cadastro_unidade_medida f = new cadastro_unidade_medida();
            f.ShowDialog();
            f.Dispose();
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
            //combo und medida
            BLLUnidadeDeMedida ubll = new BLLUnidadeDeMedida(cx);
            cbUnd.DataSource = ubll.Localizar("");
            cbUnd.DisplayMember = "umed_nome";
            cbUnd.ValueMember = "umed_cod";

        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de formulário de cadastro de categorias: ***Arquivo: cadastro_categoria.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Modelo;
using DAL;
using BLL;

namespace GUI
{
    public partial class cadastro_categoria : GUI.formulario_cadastro
    {
        public cadastro_categoria()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void LimpaTela()
        {
            txtCodigo.Clear();
            txtNome.Clear();
        }
        private void frmCadastroCategoria_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.alteraBotoes(1);
        }

        private void btInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operacao = "inserir";
            this.alteraBotoes(2);
        }

        private void btCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LimpaTela();
            this.alteraBotoes(1);
        }

        private void btSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //leitura dos dados
                ModeloCategoria modelo = new ModeloCategoria();
                modelo.CatNome = txtNome.Text;
                //obj para gravar os dados no banco
                DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
                BLLCategoria bll = new BLLCategoria(cx);
                if (this.operacao == "inserir")
                {
                    //cadastrar uma categoria
                    bll.Incluir(modelo);
                    MessageBox.Show("Cadastro efetuado: Código "+modelo.CatCod.ToString());

                }
                else
                {
                    //alterar uma categoria
                    modelo.CatCod = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
                    bll.Alterar(modelo);
                    MessageBox.Show("Cadastro alterado");
                }
                this.LimpaTela();
                this.alteraBotoes(1);
            }
            catch(Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btAlterar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.operacao = "alterar";
            this.alteraBotoes(2);
        }

        private void btExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Deseja excluir o registro?", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (d.ToString() == "Yes")
                {
                    DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
                    BLLCategoria bll = new BLLCategoria(cx);
                    bll.Excluir(Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text));
                    this.LimpaTela();
                    this.alteraBotoes(1);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Impossível excluir o registro. \n O registro esta sendo utilizado em outro local.");
                this.alteraBotoes(3);
            }
        }

        private void btLocalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            consulta_categoria f = new consulta_categoria();
            f.ShowDialog();
            if (f.codigo != 0)
            {
                DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
                BLLCategoria bll = new BLLCategoria(cx);
                ModeloCategoria modelo = bll.CarregaModeloCategoria(f.codigo);
                txtCodigo.Text = modelo.CatCod.ToString();
                txtNome.Text = modelo.CatNome;
                alteraBotoes(3);
            }
            else
            {
                this.LimpaTela();
                this.alteraBotoes(1);
            }
            f.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de tela de consulta de fornecedores: ***Arquivo: consulta_fornecedor.cs***

```
using BLL;
using DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GUI
{
    public partial class consulta_fornecedor : Form
    {
        public int codigo = 0;
        public consulta_fornecedor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btLocalizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
            BLLFornecedor bll = new BLLFornecedor(cx);
            if (rbNome.Checked == true)
            {
                dgvDados.DataSource = bll.LocalizarPorNome(txtValor.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                dgvDados.DataSource = bll.LocalizarPorCNPJ(txtValor.Text);
            }
        }

        private void frmConsultaFornecedor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btLocalizar_Click(sender, e);
            dgvDados.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Código";
            //dgvDados.Columns[0].Width = 50;
            dgvDados.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Nome";
            //dgvDados.Columns[1].Width = 700;
            dgvDados.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Razão Social";
            dgvDados.Columns[3].HeaderText = "IE";
            dgvDados.Columns[4].HeaderText = "CNPJ";
            dgvDados.Columns[5].HeaderText = "CEP";
            dgvDados.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Endereço";
            dgvDados.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Bairro";
            dgvDados.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Fone";
            dgvDados.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Celular";
            dgvDados.Columns[10].HeaderText = "E-mail";
            dgvDados.Columns[11].HeaderText = "Número";
            dgvDados.Columns[12].HeaderText = "Cidade";
            dgvDados.Columns[13].HeaderText = "Estado";
        }

        private void dgvDados_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                this.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu lugar, modificaria um pouco sua classe `DALConexao`:

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class DALConexao<TConnection>
        where TConnection : class, IDbConnection, new()
    {
        private String _stringConexao;
        private TConnection _conexao;

        public DALConexao(String dadosConexao)
        {
            this._conexao = new TConnection();
            this.StringConexao = dadosConexao;
            this._conexao.ConnectionString = dadosConexao;
        }

        public String StringConexao
        {
            get { return this._stringConexao; }
            set { this._stringConexao = value; }
        }

        public TConnection ObjetoConexao
        {
            get { return this._conexao; }
            set { this._conexao = value; }

        }
        public void Conectar()
        {
            this._conexao.Open();
        }

        public void Desconectar()
        {
            this._conexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, ela pode trabalhar tanto com o SQL Server quanto com o MySQL. Por exemplo:

```
public class SqlServerDal : DALConexao<SqlConnection> 
{
    public SqlServerDal(String dadosConexao)
        : base(dadosConexao)
    {

    }
}
public class MySqlDal : DALConexao<MySqlConnection> 
{
    public MySqlDal(String dadosConexao)
        : base(dadosConexao)
    {

    }
}
```

[`MySqlConnection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html) e outros componentes de acesso ao MySQL [podem ser instalados através deste pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/).

[Aqui tem exemplos de como montar sua *connection string*](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

---

**EDIT**

Em todos os lugares que você tiver este erro:

> Using the generic type 'DAL.DALConexao' requires 1 type arguments.

Troque:

```
DALConexao cx = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
```

Por:

```
var cx = new DALConexao<SqlConnection>(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
```

Ou ainda:

```
var cx = new SqlServerDal(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao);
```

Que é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Obrigado! vou testar.

Comment: deu erro:

`where TConnection : class, IDbConnection, new()` Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations

`public DALConexao(String dadosConexao)` Method must have a return type

Comment: @MarlonLeandro Melhorei os exemplos. Veja se fica mais claro.

Comment: Agora deu isso: Using the generic type `'DAL.DALConexao<TConnection>'` requires 1 type arguments

Comment: no Arquivo: configuracao_banco_de_dados.cs que citei ai em cima, tem que alterar algo, não?

Comment: Sim. Você precisa que eu coloque o `configuracao_banco_de_dados.cs` também?

Comment: Por gentileza. Deu esse erro também: Agora deu isso: Using the generic type `'DAL.DALConexao<TConnection>'` requires 1 type arguments. - em todos os arquivos de configuração de conexão dos form's

Comment: @MarlonLeandro Como só precisa alterar uma linha, não vou colocar o arquivo todo. A explicação vale para os demais arquivos.